Create contact using SuiteCRM api PHP
I am using SuiteCRM and have client credentials api type is set. I am able to get access token but I do not know how to create contact using api. There is nothing useful on api documentation.
Using V8 api, how can I create contacts? I have access token code which is working well.

You can use the following Curl request:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://www.roigap.com/SuiteCRM/Api/V8/module' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json' \
  -d '{
  "data": {
    "type": "Contacts",
    "id": "86ee02b3-96d2-47b3-bd6d-9e1035daff3a",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Contact name",
      "website": "www.roigap.com"
    }
  }
}'


